# Sending A embedded photo fetched from an api every 5 minutes inside a command handler commands folder

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    category: "fun",
    description: "Sends an epic meme",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
        // Grab a random property from the array
        const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];


        const img = await randomPuppy(random);
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#ff2050")
            .setDescription("HERE IS A MEME FOR YOU")
            .setImage(img);

    }


    }
```

I want to send a meme every 5 minutes but it should be random

Answer (score 1):

In main project folder create Folder with name **TimeTriggers**, in this folder create js file **randomeme.js**

Put this code into **randomeme.js** file.

```
const Discrod = require("discord.js"); 
const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

const sendRandomMeme = (bot) => {
    let Channel = bot.channels.get('ChannelID')
    const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
    // Grab a random property from the array
    const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];


    const img = await randomPuppy(random);
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#ff2050")
        .setDescription("HERE IS A MEME FOR YOU")
        .setImage(img);
    Channel.send(embed)

}

module.exports = sendRandomMeme
```

Put this code into your main js file

```
const sendRandomMeme = require('./TimeTriggers/randommeme.js')


bot.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(sendRandomMeme, 1000 * 60 * 5, bot)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    category: "fun",
    description: "Sends an epic meme",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
        // Grab a random property from the array
        let random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];


        const img = await randomPuppy(random);
        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor("#ff2050")
            .setDescription("HERE IS A MEME FOR YOU")

        // Sends your random dead unworthy and sinful memes every 5 minutes
        setInterval(function () {
            random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];
            embed.setImage(img)
            return message.channel.send(embed);
        }, 300000);

    }

}
```

Hope this works for your memes

Comment: @CrackingXPatching i mean ... looking at the site, everyone seems pretty serious, I thought i'd make answers a little bit more funnier ... my bad then